# mongo always returns null even though data is available

Tags: mongodb

i have insert few docs into my mongodb and while fetching i am always getting null as reponse
this is my get method

```
router.get('/getPersonDetails/:id', function(req, res) {
var db=req.db;
var collection=db.get('Person');
var reqId = req.params.id;
var query={'person_id':reqId}
console.log(query);
collection.findOne(query, function(err, item) {
    console.log(item);
    res.send(
            (err===null) ? {msg:item} : {msg:err}
        );
});
```

});

this is the add method

```
router.post('/addPerson', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('Person');
collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result) {
    res.send(
        (err===null) ? {msg:result} :{msg:err}
        );
});
```

});

had create db in the same hierarchy that my node project exists.

MySample out out when i tried in getAll API;

```
0:  {
  "_id": "56b1ac863a9ac81c4177fbfc"
  "{ "person_id": "1", "person_name": "gvsharma" }": ""
}
```

i think am missing something here?

i am a new learner. and please correct me where am wrong?

Comment: You need to show the part where you are getting the collection, and likely also where you are connecting to the database. Odds are on you are connecting to either 1. A different database than you think you are. 2. A different collection than you think you are. 3. You are passing a string for an ObjectId without conversion at any point in the data access layer. Depends on what the underlying driver you are using is, and how you are doing things. More information required.

Comment: hi Blakes.....Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If your query is running on this document, then query you have specified will not work. The inserted format is incorrect.
This is your data:

`{
    "_id": "56b1ac863a9ac81c4177fbfc",
    "{ "person_id": "1", "person_name": "gvsharma" }": ""
 }`

This is how it should be inserted:

```
{
  "_id": "56b1ac863a9ac81c4177fbfc",
  "person_id": "1",
  "person_name": "gvsharma"
}
```

that query will work on above document. Please check the insert query you are not getting JSON in format that you are expecting when you read req.body.